# PHP accessing multididmensional associative array

Tags: php, arrays, json, associative-array

These are my code blocks that I write:

```
$url = "http://links";
        $curl_post_data = array(
          "username" => "guest",
        );
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PORT, 8889);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$result = $curl_response;
echo $result
```

What I did try is echo the $result variables and returned as bellow:

```
  {
        "price": [
            {
                "price": "2000",
                "origin_name": "JPN",
            },
            {
                "price": "5000",
                "origin_name": "USA",
            }
        ]
   }
```

What I want and need to know is how can I get or access the value of each elements which is the `price` and `origin_name`. I've try to call it with `$result[0]['price']['origin_name'][0]` but it doesn't work and returning like below:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'price' in .... on line ...

Warning: Illegal string offset 'origin_name' in .... on line ... 
{
```

I have also try using `foreach` function written like bellow:

```
foreach($result['price'] as $res){
            echo $res[0];
}
```

but it's returning same error message:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'price' in .... on line ...

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in  .... on line ...
```

Comment: Post your entire code

Comment: Could the returned data be a JSON String? It looks like one

Comment: `$result = {` is not a normal PHP syntax, is it a json string instead?

Comment: Except that the JSON is InValid

Comment: So first you need to get the site that is producing this JSON result to fix it so that JSON is valid. Is this result produced by your code or someone elses?

Comment: @user2342558 I did rewrite the whole completion

Comment: Then ask another question, as this has been put on hold. Show us how you create this JSONString in you API

Comment: @RiggsFolly I rewrite the code. So basically I use the curl to get all the data from the link api that provided, so the json result structure is written by someone else

Comment: To the powers that be, pls re-open the question. The provided links are not so helpful. First of all, what does one do when one receives data that is poorly formatted? Instead of manually fixing it, you can use PHP to get it in shape so that it constitutes valid JSON for PHP to then decode. After that, traverse the new PHP array with array_walk_recursive() (a solution  not mentioned in the pertinent duplicate answered question). This real-world type of question requiring  multiple solutions ought to be re-opened.

Comment: Then you should contact the producer of the data and ask them to fix their API!

Comment: It appears that your API provider is supplying you with a strange "comma-saturated pretty-printed json string".  This is unfortunate for you.  You either need to compel them to fix up the json being delivered, or use an unstable repairing method.  I just happened to whack one together for you.  (It will work until it doesn't  ...yeah, that's what I just said) http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/391b30b9094fe82f2f62682f7950ea55582fc43b   ...Hmm, actually, it looks like this: http://json5.org/ have a look.

Comment: @deceze Are we looking at JSON5 here?  I don't see a json5 tag on SO.

Comment: @mickmackusa Your guess is as good as mine, OP needs to clarify and perhaps consult the producer of that data.

Comment: @RiggsFolly The thing is that's all the format that I got from the api and sadly the producer of the data probably won't fix the data since that api have been used by a lot of other corporations for a long time.

Comment: @deceze not sure what that format is called.

Comment: @mickmackusa the sad thing is producer of that data won't fix the format since it have been used by a lot of other corporations for a long time.

Comment: I think the green tick is poorly awarded then (since it won't work).   slevy1's replacement pattern doesn't look right to me.  I recommend that you limp your way through this unfortunately situation with my replacement regex pattern.  I will not be 100% reliable, but it will cover the vast majority of cases.

Comment: @deceze it seems this question is now asking: What do I do with this malformed json string since I can't control its creation?  Should this be re-opened or closed differently?

Comment: @mickmackusa It would need to be rewritten to be reopened, but since there are already answers here, rewriting the question would hose this entire thread. So, if that's really the question that needs answering, a new question shall be posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let assume from the beggining :

```
$result = '{
    "price": [
        {
            "price": "2000",
            "origin_name": "JPN"
        },
        {
            "price": "5000",
            "origin_name": "USA"
        }
    ]
}';
$resultDecoded = json_decode($result, true);
foreach ($resultDecoded["price"] as $item) {
    echo $item["price"];
}
```

The problem is the JSON String denotes an object, not an array

> NOTE:
>
> The JSON String you showed us was malformatted, no comma should be added at the end of the last Property of a JSONString Object.

Comment: Did you test that code?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Sorry, I updated the answer

Comment: Then you need to tell the OP that this code will only work if they get the data source to fix there JSON String producer

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes thanks, i did in the second update :)

Comment: Kudo to Benoit for giving this correct answers. So apparently I learn something from this new structured json format that need to be decoded first.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the result one gets back needs fixing before using it.  One can use [preg_replace()](http://php.net/preg_replace) to fix the invalid JSON.  After decoding the remedied JSON into a PHP associative array, one can use [array_pop()](http://php.net/array_pop) to extract the price array and then use [array_walk_recursive()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) to fetch the price and origin name information, as follows:

```
<?php
// take badly formatted JSON ...
$result = '{
        "price": [
            {
                "price": "2000",
                "origin_name": "JPN",
            },
            {
                "price": "5000",
                "origin_name": "USA",
            }
        ]
   }';

// ... and remove the superfluous commas:
$pat = "/(o.+),/";
$replace = "$1";
$nu_result = preg_replace($pat,$replace,$result);

// now convert JSON into PHP array and traverse it
$resultDecoded = json_decode($nu_result, true);
$arr = array_pop($resultDecoded);
array_walk_recursive($arr,function($e,$i) {
       if ($i == "price") {
            echo "price: ",$e,"\n";
       }
       else
       if ($i == "origin_name") {
           echo "origin_name: ",$e,"\n\n";
       }
});
```

See [live code](https://3v4l.org/uuNZU#output)

Comment: Actually he didn't if you check the comments under his question

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for the feedback; duly noted and amended my response.